# Writing multiple Custom Collectors in Prometheus using Python

Tags: prometheus

I am new to Prometheus and I am writing a Custom Collector to get CPU and Memory values of two firewalls. I can expand them to as many devices as I want.

Now I am opening a http server in port 8000 and getting these. So now my metrics are available in http://localhost:8000

if **name** == '**main**':
    start_http_server(8000)
    REGISTRY.register(CustomCollector())
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)

I have one Custom Collector function to return both memory and CPU for the devices which I have stored in a list.

Now when I add about 30 devices the response would become untidy and difficult to interpret.

I want to have CPU values and Memory values in seperate endpoints namely

http://localhost:8000/CPU
http://localhost:8000/Memory

So is there a way to do this?

I have two questions

1) Can we write multiple Custom Collector functions in the same script and modify their endpoints with the port remaining same?
2) Can we write multiple Custom Collector functions in the same script exposing them on different ports? (Not sure if this efficient though)

Any other ideas apart from these would also help..

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question yeah you can expose different endpoint, prometheus just need to know the endpoint to scrape it.

I would also suggest you to use exporters written by prometheus community instead writing your own if it's available.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem lately and found a solution myself but I dont see anywhere in stackoverflow so thought of sharing my solution. Basically REGISTRY is default collector registry available but you can create multiple instances as follows and start different http servers on different ports but the handle will be always '/metrics' atleast in python.

```
# For CPU
cpuregistry = CollectorRegistry()
cpuregistry.register(CpuCollector())
start_http_server(port=8000,registry=cpuregistry)
# For Mem 
memregistry = CollectorRegistry()
memregistry.register(MemCollector())
start_http_server(port=8001,registry=memregistry)
```

Using this technique, you can use different Collectors/Registry in the same script.